# System with non-skew symmetric gyroscopic matrix

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Lets take the following equations of motions of a two DOF system

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
m & 0\\
0 & L
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{u}\\
\ddot{q}
\end{array}\right]=-\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
\varphi' & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{u}\\
\dot{q}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{cc}
k & 0\\
0 & C^{-1}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
u\\
q
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}
F_{m}\\
F_{e}
\end{array}\right]$$

where $u$ is the position, q the charge, $m$ the mass, $L$ the inductance, $k$ the mechanical stiffness, $C$ the capacitance and $\varphi'$ the magnetic flux derivative with respect to the unique direction $x$. $F$ represents external forces.

I derived the the kinetic energy of this system as

$$T=\frac{1}{2}\left(m\dot{u}_{s}^{2}+L\dot{q}^{2}+\varphi'u\dot{q}\right)$$

which, for me, makes no sense since the third term in the RHS is not symmetric; i.e. it has not a $-\varphi'q\dot{u}$ couterpart. If it had, then I could understand the system as a non-natural gyroscopic system.

My intuition says that there is something wrong with this system. Following it, I tried a justification stating that for a non-natural conservative system the Jacobi's integral gives
$$\sum\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial\dot{q}}\dot{q}-\mathscr{L}=const$$

Being the Lagrangian of the system

$$\mathscr{L}=T-V=\frac{1}{2}\left(m\dot{u}_{s}^{2}+L\dot{q}^{2}+\varphi'u_{s}\dot{q}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(ku_{s}^{2}+C^{-1}q^{2}\right)$$

we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot{u}_{s}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}L\dot{q}^{2}-V=const$$

Then, recalling the above expression of the kinetic energy, we can say that the system does not conserves energy.

My question is, is that reasoning correct? Can I say this system has the wrong physics?